# Javafx disable link does not disable link until the embedded AWT window is launched

Tags: javafx

I have a sample javafx application which embeds a Swing application inside it. In my below sample application I have a link on press of which I need to launch a AWT window. I get the JrootPane of AWT window using a method getRootPane which take quite a time to launch. Hence, I am using a non FX thread to call launchWindow.

I want that as soon as I click on the link the link shall become disable and as soon as I close the newly launched window , the link shall become enable again.

But in my below sample code , the link does not become disable until the child window is launched. Please help why is that. What shall I do to fix this issue

```
public class GifViewerTest extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
    VBox box = new VBox();
    Image icon = new Image(this.getClass().getResource("/images/images.png").toExternalForm());
    
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(icon);
    box.getChildren().add(imageView);
    
    Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Test Link", imageView);
    box.getChildren().add(link);
    

    Button localLoadButton = new Button("Local load");

    link.setOnMousePressed(e ->
    {
    link.setDisable(true);

 // separate non-FX thread
            new Thread() {

                // runnable for that thread
                public void run() {
                                            
                        
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                            launchWindow(link,400, 400);

                            }
                        });
                    
                }
            }.start();
        
    });


    stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 500, 400));
    stage.show();
    
    }

    JRootPane getRootPane()
    {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 500000; i > 0; i--)
        System.out.println(i);
    ;
    return new JRootPane();
    }

    private void launchWindow(Hyperlink wcaLink,int stageWidth, int stageHeight)
    {
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();

    rootPane.setName("Sample Swing App");

    final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
        swingNode.setContent(rootPane);
        }
    });

    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    // add the following code to make sure the swing node grows with the window.
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(swingNode, 0d);

    anchorPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

    stage.setTitle("Sample JavaFx Embedding Swing");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, stageWidth, stageHeight));

    stage.show();
    stage.setOnCloseRequest((e) ->{
        wcaLink.setDisable(false);
        System.out.println("Enabling wcaLink again");
    });

    }

}
```

Comment: Your thread is completely redundant; all it does is call `Platform.runLater()`, which schedules the runnable on the FX Application Thread and exits immediately.  Use threads for long-running processes, not things that exit immediately. Then you call `getRootPane()`, which is long-running, on the FX Application thread, so the (JavaFX) UI can't be updated until that method exits, so you don't see the disabled link.

Comment: @James_D it will be really helpful if you can illustrate more. Could you please put the updated code on the answer. I am struggling with a similar issues for a long time.

Comment: I can't answer the question because it's not well enough articulated. Creating a `JRootPane` does not take a long time, so it's not at all clear what the point of your long-running loop is. It looks like you are mixing some long-running, non-UI process with your UI code. You need to start by separating those things out. Write a [mre] that is easy to read (not cluttered up with commented-out code and irrelevant stuff).

Comment: The basics are not complicated. Run long-running processes in a background thread. Run UI-related code in the UI thread. It's more complex when you mix Swing with JavaFX, because you have two UI threads and have to run the correct parts in the correct threads, but the principles are the same.

Comment: @James_D the JRootPane is returned by the Swing application which is a third party and I have very little control over their code. The Swing application is a very big and legacy application and it won't be possible for me to change their architecture. My getRootPane is just to mime the time taken by the legacy application which takes really a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic threading rules for UI development are:

1. Never run long-running code on the UI thread. This will make the UI unresponsive and prevent UI updates from happening in a prompt manner.
2. Any code that updates the UI must be run on the UI thread. This is because UI toolkits are generally single-threaded, so all access to UI elements must be made on the same thread.

Note that in order to achieve this, it's necessary for any non-UI code (which might be long-running) to be separated from the UI code. This is good practice in any case, without threading considerations, because it conforms to general principles such as separation of concerns and MVC-type design.

Since you are mixing two UI toolkits (JavaFX and Swing), you need to apply rule 2 twice, once for each toolkit. Swing components must be created and accessed on the AWT event dispatch thread, and JavaFX nodes must be created and accessed on the FX Application Thread.

Your code basically does everything the wrong way around. You create a thread whose *only* statement of execution is `Platform.runLater()`. This method simply schedules a `Runnable` to execute on the FX Application Thread and exits immediately. Since this essentially takes no time to run, there is no purpose whatsoever in creating a background thread for it.

On the other hand, the `Runnable` you schedule to execute on the FX Application Thread invokes `launchWindow()` which in turn invokes `getRootPane()`, which is a long-running method. Consequently, you block the FX Application Thread and prevent any modifications to the UI (including disabling the link) from being processed until that long-running method completes.

In theory, you should:

- Execute the long-running method on a background thread
- Create the `JRootPane` and other Swing components on the AWT event dispatch thread
- Create the `SwingNode` and do other JavaFX UI work on the FX Application thread.

From the comments, you indicate that it is impossible to separate the long-running process from the creation of the `JRootPane`, because that code belongs to a third-party legacy application which cannot separate those concerns.

The correct answer to this question is to ask the maintainers of the legacy application to fix the threading issues inherent in their code. If the authors of that code are really making such basic and fundamental errors, as you claim, then you should strongly consider not using that codebase (how many other errors can you expect there to be?) and look for another solution. I would certainly not touch any product that I knew to be written as badly as you claim that is written.

If you're forced to use that third-party application for some reason, your best option is probably to create the `JRootPane` on a background thread. This is likely to work, though it is not guaranteed and may fail at arbitrary times and break on arbitrary systems/JVMs, because Swing is bullet-proofed to some degree against threading rule violations such as this.

The strategy here would be:

Start a background thread that creates the `JRootPane` via the long-running process, and then uses `SwingUtilities.runLater()` to complete the Swing part of the code.

Here is a version of your code (cleaned up to a large degree) that uses this approach:

```
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GifViewerTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox box = new VBox();

        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Test Link");
        box.getChildren().add(link);

        link.setOnAction(e -> {
            link.setDisable(true);
            launchWindow(link, 400, 400);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 500, 400));
        stage.show();

    }

    private JRootPane getRootPane() {
        // simulate long-running process:
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return new JRootPane();
    }

    private void launchWindow(Hyperlink wcaLink, int stageWidth, int stageHeight) {

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();
            System.out.println("Load complete");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                rootPane.setName("Sample Swing App");
                rootPane.getContentPane().add(new javax.swing.JLabel("Root pane loaded"));

                swingNode.setContent(rootPane));
            });         
        });
        thread.start();
        
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        // add the following code to make sure the swing node grows with the window.
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(swingNode, 0d);

        anchorPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

        stage.setTitle("Sample JavaFx Embedding Swing");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, stageWidth, stageHeight));
        
        stage.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> {
            wcaLink.setDisable(false);
            System.out.println("Enabling wcaLink again");
        });
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

Note this shows the window immediately, which is then updated when the call to `getRootPane()` completes. If you want the window not to show until `getRootPane()` completes, you can wrap the remaining JavaFX code in `Platform.runLater()`, which you can invoke from the AWT event dispatch thread:

```
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GifViewerTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox box = new VBox();

        Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("Test Link");
        box.getChildren().add(link);

        link.setOnAction(e -> {
            link.setDisable(true);
            launchWindow(link, 400, 400);
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 500, 400));
        stage.show();

    }

    private JRootPane getRootPane() {
        // simulate long-running process:
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return new JRootPane();
    }

    private void launchWindow(Hyperlink wcaLink, int stageWidth, int stageHeight) {

        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();

            System.out.println("Load complete");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                rootPane.setName("Sample Swing App");
                rootPane.getContentPane().add(new javax.swing.JLabel("Root pane loaded"));
                swingNode.setContent(rootPane);
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
                    // add the following code to make sure the swing node grows with the window.
                    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
                    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
                    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(swingNode, 0d);
                    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(swingNode, 0d);

                    anchorPane.getChildren().add(swingNode);

                    stage.setTitle("Sample JavaFx Embedding Swing");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, stageWidth, stageHeight));
                    
                    stage.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> {
                        wcaLink.setDisable(false);
                        System.out.println("Enabling wcaLink again");
                    });
                    stage.show();
                    
                });
            });         
        });
        thread.start();
        

    }

}
```